# creating any new project

Tags: node-modules, npm-install

I tried creating two projects one with nest and one with express. There were some files missing like node_modules and package-lock.json. When I looked it up, it said that it may have been using a previous version of node already installed but that the project would still work. However, there were some dependencies missing, for example, in express it said it couldn't find express dependency when I tried to import it, the same thing with nest common, nest testing and just nest in general.

When I try to specifically try to download the necessary dependencies it doesn't work. what can I do?
I want everything my project needs to be installed in the project's folder and not rely on any global things.